# Access 2007: Auto fill field

Tags: ms-access-2007

In my UpdateForm I have 3 fields. PartNumber, Description and SerialNumber.
I use 2 tables for these. My MainTable and PartsList Table.

In my PartsList table I have the list of PartNumber in Column (0) and Description in column (1).

In my MainTable I have 4 fields: TransactionID (autoNumber), PartNumber(text), Description(text) and SerialNumber (text).

Now, In my UpdateForm I want the user to just select the PartNumber with a combo box (that also show the "Description" (I created this using the combo box wizard)). But I want to auto populate the field in my "Description" text box every time the user will enter new record and will also update my MainTable with all the values they entered in my UpdateForm.

I tried this codes in the after update of PartNumber combo box (properties):

```
Description = Partnumber.Column(1)
```

I tried also:

```
me.Description.value=me.PartNumber.column(1)
```

both codes unsuccessful.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a doable thing, and I would recommend looking into form_dirty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please say more about how `me.Description.value=me.PartNumber.column(1)` was unsuccessful.  If it gave you an error, please add the full text of the error message to your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have correctly understand your answer, but try this :

```
Private Sub Partnumber_Change()
  Description = Partnumber.Column(1)
End Sub
```